# i cant run a code for data normalization maxmin

Tags: java, methods

I am learning a java , and I am trying to write a code about data normalization using method but when i making call between method its give me a error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:  
>       Syntax error on token "int", new expected 
>       Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer 
>       a cannot be resolved to a type 
>       Syntax error on token "int", new expected 
>       Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer 
>       b cannot be resolved to a type 
>       Syntax error on token ";", byte expected after this token 
>       Duplicate local variable donusmusVeri 
>       veri cannot be resolved to a type 
>       The target type of this expression must be a functional interface 
>       Syntax error on token "-", :: expected 
>       Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte[] to double[]

```
at Normalization.minMaxNormalization(Normalization.java:38)
at Normalization.main(Normalization.java:52)
```

this is my code :

```
public class Normalization {

    int minFind(int data[]) {
        int min = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (min < data[i]) {
                min = data[i];

            }
        }

        return min;
    }

    int maxFind(data y[]) {
        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i > 4; i++) {
            if (max > data[i]) {
                max = data[i];

            }
        }

        return max;
    }

    double[] minMaxNormalization(int data[]){
        double[] donusmusVeri=new double[data.length];
        double MIN= 0.0;double MAX= 0.0;
        MIN=  minFind(int data []); 
        MAX=   maxFind(int data[]); 

        [] donusmusVeri= ( veri[]-MIN/ MAX -MIN); 

        return donusmusVeri;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] X = { 30, 36, 45, 50, 62 };
        double[] Xx = new double[X.length];
        Normalization nm = new Normalization();
        Xx = nm.minMaxNormalization(X);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            System.out.println(X[j]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Xx.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(Xx[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Which one is line 38 in Normalization.java?

Comment: Your code does not compile: `MIN =  minFind(int data []); ` and `MAX = maxFind(int data[]);`

Comment: ... And several other mistakes. Enter the code in an IDE and see what gets underlined.

Comment: `[] donusmusVeri= ( veri[]-MIN/ MAX -MIN);` ... what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- `int maxFind(data y[]){` you should expect it to be accepting array of integer values like `int maxFind(int data[]){`
- Your code below:

  ```
  double MIN= 0.0;double MAX= 0.0;
  MIN=  minFind(int data []); 
  MAX=   maxFind(int data[]); 
  [] donusmusVeri= ( veri[]-MIN/ MAX -MIN);//not sure what you are trying to do here
  ```

See that min/maxFind method returns integer, so you need your MIN/MAX variable of type integer and not as double.

Comment: [] donusmusVeri= ( data[]-MIN/ MAX -MIN);

Comment: i dont know how i will calling min and max after that i must change from int to double . i understand but i cant do it